# Sitecore Azure search suggesting index rebuild error

Tags: azure, azure-search

I have implemented Sitecore Suggesting search on Sitecore 9.2. based on https://sitecore.namics.com/2018/06/15/sitecore-9-azure-search-suggestions/ 
but when I rebuild indexes, I am getting error:

> Job started: Index_Update_IndexName=custom-master-index|#Exception:
>   System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown
>   by the target of an invocation. ---> System.AggregateException: One or
>   more errors occurred. --->
>   Sitecore.ContentSearch.Azure.Http.Exceptions.BadRequestException:
>   Error in the request URI, headers, or body --->
>   Sitecore.ContentSearch.Azure.Http.Exceptions.AzureSearchServiceRESTCallException:
>   {"error":{"code":"","message":"This index has suggesters defined in it
>   that cannot be removed. This error is caused by attempting to update
>   an index without including all of its existing suggesters or by
>   attempting to update an index that was created/updated with a newer
>   version of the API."}}    --- End of inner exception stack trace ---

Error happend here at update logic:

```
 protected override IndexDefinition SyncRemoteService(IndexDefinition sourceIndexDefinition, IEnumerable<IndexedField> incomingFields)
        {
            IEnumerable<IndexedField> mainFields = sourceIndexDefinition?.Fields ?? (IEnumerable<IndexedField>)new List<IndexedField>();
            incomingFields = incomingFields ?? (IEnumerable<IndexedField>)new List<IndexedField>();
            bool isModified1;
            IEnumerable<IndexedField> indexedFields = this.MergeFields(mainFields, incomingFields, out isModified1);
            if (!isModified1 && sourceIndexDefinition != null)
                return new IndexDefinition(sourceIndexDefinition.AnalyzerDefinitions, indexedFields);
            var index = this.ManagmentOperations.GetIndex();
            if (index == null)
            {
                IndexDefinition indexDefinition = new CloudIndexDefinition(this.AnalyzerRepository.GetAnalyzers(), indexedFields);
                this.ManagmentOperations.CreateIndex(indexDefinition);
                return indexDefinition;
            }
            bool isModified2;
            IEnumerable<IndexedField> fields = this.MergeFields(index.Fields, indexedFields, out isModified2);
            var indexDefinition1 = new CloudIndexDefinition(index.AnalyzerDefinitions, fields);
            if (isModified2)
                this.ManagmentOperations.UpdateIndex(indexDefinition1);
            return indexDefinition1;
        }
```

I tried different api versions to at **cloud.search**, but issue is the same.

any advice ?

Comment: Hi , Can you try recreating the index in Azure and then rebuild index?

Comment: @AbhayDhar i did but issue is repeating

Comment: Are you sure that you have also properly patched the configuration based on this file https://gist.github.com/error505/057440f2b649f6eaac6cf674bd295b30#file-yourprojectname-foundation-search-suggestions-config ?

Comment: @PeterProcházka yes I have it at configs